# How to do scroll inside div using puppeteer?

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
      if(document.querySelector('div.U1vjCc')!=null)
           {
            for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
              console.log(i);
              document.querySelector('div.U1vjCc').scrollBy(0, 6000);
            }
           }
}
```

here div.U1vjCc is querySelector of google movie review.
my approach is not working.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030394/how-to-scroll-inside-a-div-with-puppeteer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scroll inside a div with Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030394/how-to-scroll-inside-a-div-with-puppeteer)