# Scroll inside div doesn't wrk with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer, infinite-scroll

I try to scroll area inside div using Puppeteer.

I tried to follow these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67490337 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/52031392 but it didn't work.

Page I try to scroll - https://yandex.ru/profile/1899402108

My code looks like this:

```
const scrollable_section = '.business-tab-wrapper__content';
await this.page.waitForSelector('.business-reviews-card-view__review');

await this.page.evaluate(selector => {
  const scrollableSection = document.querySelector(selector);

  scrollableSection.scrollTop = scrollableSection.offsetHeight;
}, scrollable_section);
```

Previously tried this code but it didn't work too:

```
await this.page.evaluate(async () => {
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    let totalHeight = 0;
    const distance = 100;
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      const scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
      window.scrollBy(0, distance);
      totalHeight += distance;

      if (totalHeight >= scrollHeight) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        resolve();
      }
    }, 100);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you did not choose the right element to scroll.

***in the first example***, you chose `.business-tab-wrapper__content` as your scrollable element, *but* this is not a scrollable element. If you would inspect it, you will see that its height is 0, and basically, it is a line separator (I believe that you wanted to scroll *to* it).  in that example, you should choose `.scroll__content` as your `scrollable_section` and scroll in it to where you want (like the `offsetHeight` of `.business-tab-wrapper__content`.

***in the second example*** you try to scroll the document's body, *but again*, the body itself is not scrollable.

***so to sum it up*** - you need to select the *right* scrollable `div` and that scroll it to the offset that you'd like

Comment: Any examples?            a