# Puppeteer scrolling doesn't fetch new page content

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, web-scraping, puppeteer

**The problem**

I am trying to retrieve the HTML source of [an entire Google Maps page](https://www.google.com/maps/@41.9128478,-87.808076,11z/data=!4m2!11m1!2sJ1hSE9TaCGi4u4zFeqFDOj8weXjZRQ?entry=ttu) using [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) but I am running into issues with the page's load-on-scroll feature. This map has 27 places, but when I retrieve using the puppeteer code below it only retrieves the first 19 (i.e. the ones that load automatically) but not the remainder that load when you scroll. I'd like to be able to do this for other similar pages, too. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030394/how-to-scroll-inside-a-div-with-puppeteer) about puppeteer and scrolling but am not sure it is relevant here since the scroll window doesn't have a clear div name.

**What I have tried**

I tried configuring my cursor in Puppeteer to be in the right place in the window, but it doesn't seem to have helped. I have tried increasing the number of scrolls too, to no avail.

```
    googleMapsURL = 'https://www.google.com/maps/@41.9128478,-87.808076,11z/data=!4m2!11m1!2sJ1hSE9TaCGi4u4zFeqFDOj8weXjZRQ?entry=ttu'



function scrapeGoogleMaps() {
    return puppeteer.launch()
        .then(browser => browser.newPage())
        .then(page => {
            return page.goto(googleMapsURL, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
                .then(() => page);
        })
        .then(page => {
            const scrollCount = 10;
            const scrollInterval = 1000; // milliseconds

             // Function to scroll and wait for content to load
            const scrollAndLoad = () => {
                return page.evaluate(scrollPercentage => {
                    const innerHeight = window.innerHeight;
                    const scrollX = window.innerWidth * 0.05;
                    window.scrollTo(scrollX, innerHeight / 2);
                    console.log('Inner Height:', innerHeight);
                    console.log('Scroll X:', scrollX);
                }, 0.05).then(() => {
                    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, scrollInterval));
                });
            };

            // Perform scrolling sequentially
            let promiseChain = Promise.resolve();
            for (let i = 0; i < scrollCount; i++) {
                promiseChain = promiseChain.then(scrollAndLoad);
            }

            // After all scrolling, capture the content
            return promiseChain.then(() => page.content());
        })
        .then(content => {
            console.log("Should print the full content, but only prints the first 19 results";
            console.log(content);
            return content;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error during scraping:', error);
            throw error;
        });
}

scrapeGoogleMaps()
    .then(() => console.log('Scraping completed successfully.'))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error during scraping:', error))
    .finally(() => process.exit());
```

Answer (score 0):

I was ultimately able to solve this by using the "PageDown" instruction instead of "ScrollDown".